# Selenium open browser and set focus

Tags: testing, user-interface, selenium, browser, focus

I am having trouble, running selenium tests for my web gui ,sometimes when the test starts the browser open but the focus is still on the eclipse(I see eclipse window rather than browser ) which then throws errors like "Button could not be found" or link not found.

Does anyone have idea how to set focus on opened browser whenever the selenium test starts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if the browser is focused or not.
The errors most likely occur because of another circumstance.

Which Version of Selenium do you use?

If you are not already using Webdriver(Selenium 2), I would suggest switching to it.

With Webdriver 2 you can also use

```
windowFocus()
```

Comment: It does matter !!! If you have a script which clicks on the links and type user name and password and if the window is not active then it will throw error (you can try that).......

Comment: So tell me which version of selenium do you use? you provide so little information. also what coding language?

Comment: BUT Thanks for advising me using webdriver ..I will switch

Comment: I was not using Web Driver earlier.. I am using Java !! Using webdriver it sorts all the issues ...thanks mate